# receiving values of flash games through php language

Tags: php, flash

I want to use flash games on my website and I was trying to use come2play games..

everything is fine and I wrote a script to enable my users to play.

the only problem is that I can't or don't know how to save game's state and result.

My main question is how to retrieve data through flash games in php

I search their website and here is an example to do that :

http://www.come2play.com/API_inner.asp?f=1&newsid=582

but in php how can I retrieve these objects

http://www.come2play.com/API_inner.asp?f=1&newsid=647

I contacted them for 4-5 times but no answer

please give me a hint to retrieve the game's data through php language.

Comment: Are you a registered publisher with Come2Play?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. It's impossible for PHP to access flash directly even. The 'examples' you linked are examples for the server (ie owned by come2play) that does multiplayer processing.

What you can do is if you are making your own game, make it communicate with the server. You can do simple stuff such as loading urls that contains what you want to send.